# ftp_nlist() somtimes return the path sometimes not

Tags: php, ftp, php-7.2

I encounter somthing strange : ftp_nlist() somtimes return the path sometimes not. The only things I change is the server I am connected on.

When I do

```
$fileList = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/path/to/my/folder/prefix*")
```

on serveur 1 I get

```
$fileList = ["/path/to/my/folder/prefix1.txt", "/path/to/my/folder/prefix2.txt"]
```

On server 2 I get

```
$fileList = ["prefix1.txt", "prefix2.txt"]
```

What is happening ?

Comment: I think this is server related issue. A 'quick fix' might be to use [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks for the quick fix I did not thought to baseName()